A universal effective epimorphism which is not an effective descent morphism for the codomain fibration
Suppose $\mathcal{C}$ is a category with finite limits. Recall that a morphism $f : X \to Y$ is an effective epimorphism if the (augmented, truncated) Čech nerve $X \times_Y X \rightrightarrows X \overset{f}{\to} Y$ of $f$ is a coequalizer diagram and that $f$ is a universal effective epimorphism if for any $Y' \to Y$ the projection $X \times_Y Y' \to Y'$ is an effective epimorphism.
Universal effective epimorphisms are descent morphisms with respect to the codomain fibration, meaning the comparison functor
$$\mathcal{C}_{/Y} \to \lim\left(\mathcal{C}_{/X} \rightrightarrows \mathcal{C}_{/X \times_Y X} \mathrel{\substack{\textstyle\rightarrow\\[-0.6ex] \textstyle\rightarrow \\[-0.6ex] \textstyle\rightarrow}} \mathcal{C}_{/X \times_Y X \times_Y X} \right)$$
is fully faithful. The limit above is of course a $2$-limit. In nice cases, e.g. if $\mathcal{C}$ is Barr-exact or is the category of (affine) schemes, this comparison functor is in fact an equivalence.
What's an example where $f$ is a universal effective epimorphism but the comparison functor is not an equivalence? My motivation is that I would like to find a "reason" why universal effective epimorphisms are effective descent morphisms for the codomain fibration on $\mathsf{Aff}$, in the hopes of generalizing this to derived/spectral AG.
